# How to convert any document format to jpg file in linux os

Tags: linux, format, document, jpeg

How can I convert or snapshot any format of document (word,excell,power point,pdf) to jpeg picture using software on linux.
Do you have a free software I recommend to use free software or open source.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to automate this in the command line, or is GUI ok?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs in Stack Overflow btw. Should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your list of formats is open-ended, there are tools for the ones you mention but hardly for "any document format" (MacWrite 1.0 anyone?). Also it would help if you could describe what sort of output you are looking for - should there be one JPEG per page, or a really tall single-column JPEG for a multi-page document?

Answer (score 0):

try looking [here](http://www.linux-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/339-how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-linux/) for results, if this doesn't work try searching for "snapshot in linux how to"